# How can i check in Postgresql if specific index is loaded to memory?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Is there any way to check if index is loaded to memory?

Answer (score 5):

Check the contrib module [pg_buffercache](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgbuffercache.html)

After installation you can use this query to see if the table and index are in the buffercache:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    relname
FROM
    pg_buffercache
        JOIN pg_class USING (relfilenode)
WHERE
    relname IN('your_tablename','your_index_name');
```

Comment: I checked this, but it doesn't help. Database can use the index but read it from hard disk every time instead of memory.

Comment: Show us your relevant datamodel, query and the result from EXPLAIN ANALYZE. Without this information it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Why should this matter? I know the name of the index that query is using and checked with EXPLAIN ANALYZE that postgresql is actually use it, I just want to check that when it scans this index it doesn't reading that from hard disk every time

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Are you 200% sure the complete index is read from disk when it's already in memory? This would be very strange, that would make memory useless. And it's not. Did you check the page numbers (relblocknumber) of the index as well?

Comment: I'm sure that is reading from hard disk because of high IO load when I run the query. The settings of shared_buffers is 2GB, effective_cache_size is also 2GB, the index is only 350MB, so it should fit to the memory. I don't understand why Postgres keep reading from hard disk..

Comment: Regarding to relblocknumber, i will read about this in google and then come back with an answer.

Comment: "The settings of shared_buffers is 2GB, effective_cache_size is also 2GB" That is imho a very strange setting because shared_buffers should be 3 to 4 times smaller as the effective_cache_size. effective_cache_size could be 70 to 80 percent of the available RAM in the server. Can you match the IO load with the single query that has problems? Or could it be some other PostgreSQL process?

Comment: I'm trying to do a stress test with pgbench, tried it with one connection and with concurrent connection either. When i run the query from psql or pgadmin3 it doesn't take much time and I don't have enough time to see IO load. But when i do it from pgbench for one minute, i clearly see high IO load. That's why I want to check if index in memory.

Comment: Even when an index is used, at least part of the actual table must be read as well.  That's because of Postgres's implementation of MVCC: Once it finds a row via the index, it has to read from the table to find out if that row is visible.  So both the indix _and_ the indexed rows must fit in memory to avoid disk i/o.

Answer (score 2):

Note that PostgreSQL can't execute queries just based on the index data.  It has to visit the data in order to determine what information is visible from the perspective of the query; that information is only in the rows themselves, not in the index.  It's quite possible the index is all in RAM, but you're still seeing heavy I/O because the table doesn't fit there.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PgFincore](http://villemain.org/projects/pgfincore) for that.

Note that this question really has a two step solution because PostgreSQL has a two-level caching mechanism.  pg_buffercache is the right tool for examining the PostgreSQL shared buffer cache.  pgfincore is the right tool for examining the operating system's cache.

Comment: select * from pgfincore('tablename'); returns >>ERROR:  fincore(91, 0, 1073741824, 0x22a83a0): Invalid argument<< where pgfadvise_willneed runs without error, do you know whats wrong?